# Visual Studio + IIS + SVN source switch

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, project-lifecycle

I have a solution with few modules (by module I mean MVC application, common code libs, some web services etc). Release procedure is trunk > test > live. When everything is OK it works good. I collect new requirements I work on them, than I release to test and move from test to live. Sometimes requirements force me to do deeper refactorization what initially can produce unstabile base. So when I am in the middle of work I got new super pending requirement which can not wait and client force me to release ASAP. Sometimes it is hard to negotiate because they can not understand that simple change of label can take a day or two... So I need some smart solution how to simply switch between sources in terms of SVN, Visual Studio and IIS.

On super pending request comming:
I "switch" to live now my VS, my IIS and SVN points to live code, so I change the label, commit to live, release to test, and than to live.

What is the good approach to achive that?

Comment: Multiple checkouts / IIS webapps of trunk, test and live?

Comment: You suggest to create le say two folders with sources on my dev machie: live and dev. This is easy bit. For all my web apps I use IIS (virtual folders) http://localhost/app1 or http://localhost/webservice1. So when I switch from dev to live I need to change all paths in IIS. Is there a way how switch IIS automaticly?

Comment: Why not have three *sets* of IIS virtual folders? One set each for dev, test and live.

Comment: What do you mean by set? Let say there is a virtual folder localhost/webservice1 once it points to code/dev once to code/live how to achive that?

Comment: Have a virtual folder `localhost/dev/webservice` that points to `code/dev/webservice`, and another virtual folder `localhost/live/webservice` that points to `code/live/webservice`. Does that make sense?

Comment: it does. but i do not know how to do that virtual folder is localhost/virtual i do not know if this is possible to make localhost/prefix/virtual second thing is that url change is not good for me as my references point to localhost/service i do not want to change it manually.

Comment: Hmmm, then you would create a new virtual folder `localhost/live/webservice` which points to `code/live/webservice` and *remember* that `localhost/webservice` points to `code/dev/webservice` Does that work for you?